# Regex capture groups confusion

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text

> Jul 31, 2015 - Departure 2 stops Total travel time:20 h 40 m
>   Aug 26, 2015 - Return 1 stop Total travel time:19 h 0 m Chicago
>   nonstop

I want to get the digit that precedes text that looks like "stop(s)" and all instances of "nonstop", however I want both to be in the same capture group.

I wrote this regex
`(\d)(?:\Wstops?)|(nonstop)`

This does what I want but as you see it consists of two capture groups (group #1 for the digits and group #2 for 'nonstop'), can this be done with a single capture group?

My other question, is it possible to directly return 'nonstop' as 0 using regex, instead of processing the text in code later on?

Here is a live demo of my regex: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iF0cR6/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use positive [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d(?=\Wstops?)|nonstop").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

- `\\d(?=\Wstops?)` matches all the digits only if it's followed by a non-word character again followed by the string `stop` or `stops`
- `|` OR
- `nonstop` match the string `nonstop`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Mind explaining the positive lookahead assertion? Or linking some material? I'm still new to regex. Thanks Raj!

Comment: Anyone mind explaining why `(\d(?:\Wstops?))` gets '5 stops' as a match, while the 'stops' is inside a non-capturing group? As explained I have to use a lookahead assertion but I'm still confused. Is nesting a non-capturing group inside a capturing group wrong or meaningless?

Comment: @prettyvoid but the whole was inside a capturing group. Explained, ask if there is any further doubts.

Comment: Can you please give this a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407935/regex-negative-lookahead-unexpected-results?