# Regex negative lookahead, unexpected results

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text:

```
Jul 31, 2015 - Aug 27, 2015
Jul 31, 2015 - Aug 27, 2015
Aug 27, 2015
Jul 31, 2015 Data1
Jul 31, 2015 Data2
Jul 31, 2015
Jul 31, 2015
```

I want to match all dates except those that have a date next to them. So basically the dates from Line 3 and forward.

I wrote this regex
`((?:Jul|Aug)\W\d+\W+\d+)` This finds all the dates in the text.

Then to achieve what I want I thought that I have to use a negative lookahead like so
`((?:Jul|Aug)\W\d+\W+\d+(?! - Aug 27, 2015))`

But the results is not what I was expecting. What am I doing wrong here?

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/eX8yF8/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use anchors `^` and `$` to force your regex engine to match from start and end of string and use `.*` in your negative look ahead :

```
^((?:Jul|Aug)\W\d+\W+\d+)(?!.*(?:Jul|Aug)\W\d+\W+\d+).*(?:$|)
```

see demo https://regex101.com/r/dT6fY3/2

If you want to refuse that too you can use a negative look-behind too :

```
(?<! - )((?:Jul|Aug)\W\d+\W+\d+)(?!.*(?:Jul|Aug)\W\d+\W+\d+)
```

see demo https://regex101.com/r/eX8yF8/8

Comment: Thanks Kasra, but apparently I wasn't very clear in my original question. I don't want to use anchors because the data isn't exactly like I put it inside my first post above. Check this please for a more accurate demo of the data: https://regex101.com/r/eX8yF8/6 I want to find all dates except the dates that come like (Date - Date).

Comment: @prettyvoid Welcome! let me see

Comment: Thanks, the last expression is what I needed! Even though I still need time to understand it fully. Can you please tell me if it's possible to further extend the expression to exclude dates that have "Arrives On" before it? Like the last match in your last link. Also one other thing, can you explain what's happening in the regex that i originally wrote at this link https://regex101.com/r/eX8yF8/2 ? Sorry for the troubles, I'm learning regex I promise.

Comment: @prettyvoid yes add it on negative look behind https://regex101.com/r/eX8yF8/9 and in your link you have putted the negative look-ahead after the last `\d+` so it doesn't match it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use anchors and word boundary.

```
"(?m)^(?:Jul|Aug)\\W\\d+\\W+\\d+\\b(?! - Aug 27, 2015$).*"
```

or

```
"(?m)^(?:Jul|Aug)\\W\\d+\\W+\\d+\\b(?! - (?:Jul|Aug)\\W\\d+\\W+\\d+$).*"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eX8yF8/3)

Comment: Please see my comment to Kasra. This is not what I was looking for unfortunately. Thanks again :)

Comment: I would like to see your attempt Raj even though Kasra already got it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
(?<!.)(?:Jul|Aug)\W\d+\W+\d+\b(?! - Aug 27, 2015)
```

Edit: Sorry, I read your question as "match 3 lines" not "line 3 and forward"

Answer (score 0):

`^(?<month>\w{3}) (?<day>\d{1,2}), (?<year>\d{4})(?! - \w{3}\s+\d{1,2}, \d{4})[ \t]*(?<data>.*?)$`
This is a little verbose, but seems to work fine. ;)